# Undefined method The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, repository

i want to delete a product after a known date 
this is my Controller :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $productsInitial = $em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product')->findAll();

    $productsAfterdelete=$em->getRepository('ProductBundle:Product')->deleteApresDure($productsInitial);


    return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', array(
        'products' => $productsAfterdelete,
    ));
}
```

my function in repository class :

```
public function deleteApresDuree($products)
    {
        $datenow=new \DateTimeImmutable();
        foreach ($products as $produit){
            $datecreation=$produit->getCreatedDate();
            $result = $datecreation->format('Y-m-d');
            $date_fin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($result.' +15 days'));
            if ( $datenow>$date_fin )
            {
                unset($products[$produit]);
                array_values($products);

            }
        }
    return $products;

    }
```

> /**
>    * Produit
>    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
>    * @Vich\Uploadable
>    * @ORM\Table(name="produit")
>    */

error :

> Undefined method 'deleteApresDure'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

pleaaase ANY HELP !!

Comment: The error message means your repository is not properly mapped to the entity.  Make sure the cache has been cleared and that you have no typos.  Other more obscure things could also be wrong.  There are several hundred other questions with the exact same problem.

Comment: i mention that ! that i didn't have any annotation problem, i've searched in the several hundrer others question and it was a different problem.

Comment: any way i copied my function to the controller and it worked thnx by the way

Comment: Glad it is working but what you described is more of a hack than a solution.  In the long run, figuring out how to use custom repositories will pay off.

Comment: yep i know that i didn't have the time to read about reposotories i'll do it later thank you

Answer (score 1):

you should change `repositoryClass="\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository` with `repositoryClass="ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository`

Comment: thanks but i did all the possibilities for the annotation same error

Comment: be sure to clean your cache, or do the test in the dev environment (which always regenerate the cache).

Comment: if it doesn't work post your **full** Entity and Repository file.

Comment: i've changed the files now i execute my function in the Controller file and it work thank you

Comment: @ste why? Can you describe the source of the issue?